# iText flattening issue with watermark text

Tags: c#, printing, itext, watermark

I am using iTextSharp to add watermarks to existing documents that are in PDF format. I read them in, create a PdfTemplate object, add the watermark text, color, transparency, etc... to this PdfTemplate, then add the template to a PdfContentByte that I get using PdfWriter.DirectContent.

This solution has been working for a while for all documents that I throw at it, but for some reason a few particular PDFs have been printing with an opaque rectangle around the watermark text.

I have tried a number of things already, including setting the PdfGState's OverPrintMode to 1, opening the generated file after it is created and then using PdfStamper's setFormFlattening and setFreeTextFlattening before saving a new copy... Nothing has worked so far.

The issue is that I don't care about flattening form fields or buttons, I just want to flatten all the layers of the document after I have generated the entire thing. Is this even possible with the iText API?

Comment: I'm still struggling with this one. I managed to solve some of my problem by setting the TextKnockout property of my PdfGState instance to false. This is literally the worst documented feature I have seen, a google search only gives three results... Has anyone ever been able to change their PdfTemplate so that it does not place an opaque box around text?

Comment: PdfTemplate doesn't do that on its own.  It just wraps whatever drawing commands are already present.  Can we see some code/sample PDFs?

Comment: @Mark Storer It seems to be an issue with transparency, as if the PDF is an older version that doesn't respect the PdfGState's transparency property. Also, if I print this document to a new file using a virtual printer, it looks fine. Only when I print it directly to a physical printer (which printer doesn't appear to matter, I've tried a few) does the issue show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, coming back to close this one out since I solved it a long time ago:

The issue was that the pdfs having the issue were very old (v1.3 of the PDF standard) and did not support the transparency that was a part of the watermark element.

I got around this by printing the old PDF via a virtual printer to a temporary file, then continuing to process that file, which was now a newer version of the PDF standard.